# Python using re.sub with string having special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to replace the exact match in a string with a value with following code but the result is not the expected one

```
import re

expression = "IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1] + IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1][2]"
token = "IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1]"
token_value = "0"
expression = re.sub(r'\b%s(?=\W)' % re.escape(token), token_value, expression)
print(expression)
```

It gives me `0 + 0[2]` but I expect it to be `0 + IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1][2]`.

I just want to replace the exact match e.g. `IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1]` but not `IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1][2]`.

Comment: Use `\s` instead of `\W`

Comment: Or just `expression = expression.replace(token, token_value, 1)` to replace the first occurrence.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to use negative lookahead for all non space characters, basically the pattern becomes `'%s(?!\S)'` which means after the expression token there should not be anything other thana space, tab or newline.

Overall, it'd look like

```
    expression = "IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1] + IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1][2]"
    token = "IO_NIP_PORT_ID_TABLE2[1]"
    token_value = "0"

    expression = re.sub(r'%s(?!\S)' % re.escape(token), token_value, expression)

    print(expression)
```